# How to avoid double cursor/caret in Codemirror textfield?

Tags: codemirror

I use Codemirror to edit some javascript code.
In Chrome the editor show two cursors, a small and a large one:

[image]

In Firefox there is another artefact next to the cursor:

[image]

In both browsers initially there is an artefact at the beginning of the text:

[image]

I am assuming its a css clash with my current page because it works well outside my page, but cant find the clash anywhere. Has anyone had similar issues or know what to do?

I am able to influence the colors of the two cursors as follows:

```
.CodeMirror {
     caret-color: red;
}


.CodeMirror-cursor {    
    background-color: blue;
    width:0px;
    border:none;
}
```

How can I hide the extra small red caret (or increase its size and hide the blue caret)? I tried to set caret-color to transparent. However, then still a small gray line remains. I am able to hide the large line but did not manage to correct the size of the small caret.

Example code:

```
var container = document.createElement('div');
this.appendChild(container);   

this.__codeMirror = window.CodeMirror(container,  
              {
                value: self.value,
                mode: self.mode,
                lineNumbers: false, 
                matchBrackets: true,
                continueComments: "Enter",
                extraKeys: {"Ctrl-Q": "toggleComment"}
              }
            );
```

Related question:

- [Codemirror cursor position offset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7858585/codemirror-cursor-position-offset)

Comment: inspect your codemirror element and find the `.CodeMirror-cursors` element, there should be an element called `.CodeMirror-cursor` inside, and if there is anything else in there, make the height 0.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. There is only one .CodeMirror-cursor element inside the .CodeMirror-cursors element. I updated my question.

Comment: Can you create a codepen or jsfiddle to try to reproduce this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue has been caused by some css settings for div:

```
treez-section div {
  padding-left: 1px;
  padding-right: 1px;
  border-style:none;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
}
```

fixed by only considering first level children:

```
treez-section > div {
  padding-left: 1px;
  padding-right: 1px;
  border-style:none;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
}
```